# Storyboards and programmatically views

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, xib

I'm totally lost in this issue. I have been working with storyboards, I have created a navigation controller with tableviews and some stuff. There are `Services` in each row of the tableview and I need to create one detail view for each service.

There are a lot of services, so I can't create them in the storyboard. The idea is to download the `Services` from a webservice (number of parameters, types of each one, etc..) and add as textfields / buttons as appropriate to the `Service`.

So, my problems and questions are:

1) Can I combine Storyboards and views programmatically? When I create a `NewView` in `MyTableviewClass`, should I do it in my `prepareforsegue` method? How can I show it in the screen without loosing my navigation controller? this is what I have (it doesn't work: it says to me that there is no segue with name 'Service1' ) :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NextLevel"]) {
    [segue.destinationViewController setActualNodo:[actualNodo getSonAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
} else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Service1"]) {
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    UIView *myview  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    [myview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:myview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myview]; }
```

Any book or reference is welcomed but I couldn't find anything similar. Is this very complicated in iOS? I have done a similar thing in Java. I have read about generating interfaces dynamically with XIBs but, sincerely, I don't know what it is.. 
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create a `StoryBoard` with a view and then add views programmatically to it.

You should not try creating a view within your `prepareForSegue` method. This really should be used for passing objects to another `ViewController`.

I would suggest this to you. Go back to your `StoryBoard` and create a new UIViewController scene.  Click on your first scene and `CTRL` drag to the new scene.  Next, click on your segue and give it a name.

**Step 1:**

Create a new class called **ServicesViewController** and make sure it's a subclass of `UIViewController:

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Step 2:**

Go back to your `StoryBoard` and click on scene so that it is selected. Next, click on the `Files Owner` and finally click on the class info button (the third button) and finally select your `ServiceViewController` class you just created.

[image]

**Step 3:**

Back in your `ServicesViewController` in the `didSelectRowAtIndex` method call your seque:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME" sender:nil];
}
```

For now, clean out all the code in your `prepareForSegue` method and just get the transition down first.

Comment: At first thank you for your answer. So, I could create a new ViewController (empty) in my storyboard, associate it to my 'ServiceView' class and generate the interface programmatically in the ViewDidLoad, right?

Comment: I updated my answer with more detail. I hope this helps you more! Disregard the UImageView on the scene, it's one from my project It should be a blank white view on yours.

Comment: How about adding buttons programatically upon UIButton press to storyboard view?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Flea's answer, if you need to keep the navigation controller, just create a push segue in your storyboard by control dragging from the file owner icon (the yellow box under your view controller's view) of the table view controller to the ServiceViewController you added to the storyboard, this should show a popup window where you can select "push" as the type of the segue. Next, select the segue and in the attribute inspector (the fourth button, next to the one in the snapshot) and in the "Identifier" text field type in a unique identifier for your segue, such as `serviceSegue`.

At this point, using Flea's code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"serviceSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

And in the code you posted:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"serviceSegue"]) 
        [segue.destinationViewController setActualNodo:[actualNodo getSonAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the other segue "Service1", but if you want to change the view of the TableViewController, segues are not the way to do it. If anything you should do it in the  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method depending on the row selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (You want to transition to other view controller)
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"serviceSegue" sender:nil];
     else
         Change your view here.
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just have multiple cells in a tableView. Instead of using segues you can simply create different cells with different identifiers and show or hide them based on what services are detected in your services array which is populated from your web service.

Comment: Thank you for your help, MarkM, but my problem is how I could generate the interface dynamically once I have my tableview working. Anyway I think that I can keep working with the upper answer.